# How to deploy WebLogic's JMS module to another server

Tags: deployment, jms, weblogic, weblogic9.x

If I have a JMS module defined in a file (my-module-jms.xml) copied from one of WebLogic 9.x domains, then is there a way to deploy that module to another WebLogic with minimal effort using either WebLogic Administration Console or WLST?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found an answer in [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/jms_admin/deployjms.html#1063900).